# Connections between Lindblad equation and black holes

Tags: black-holes, stochastic-processes

There have been some investigations about wave function collapse caused by gravitation. And as is known, Lindblad equation can be regarded as a formal description of stochastic collapse of wave function. How could Lindbladian connect with black holes?